# How would I find optimal production quantities to maximize profit in R?

Tags: r, function, optimization, constraints

I'm new to R and have tried looking for the correct way to write this. I'm hoping to find optimal production amounts given the constraints to maximize profit. I apologize if this is a newb question - any help would be so greatly appreciated!

M1, M2, and M3 represent quantities of raw materials needed for each unit of product. X represents a product used outdoors, and Y represents a product used indoors.

Some constraints:
For every unit of X, the following raw material amounts are required:

- M1 = 5
- M2 = 2
- M3 = 3

For every unit of Y, the following raw material amounts are required:

- M1 = 6
- M2 = 1
- M3 = 3

Total raw material available constraints:

- Total M1 cannot exceed 26
- Total M2 cannot exceed 12
- Total M3 cannot exceed 15

I am trying to use profit_indoor and profit_outdoor to represent the profit per each product.

```
prod_vec <- c()
total_profit_fun <- function(prod_vec){
production <- sum(prod_vec[1:2])

x <- prod_vec[1]
y <- prod_vec[2]

profit_indoor <- 70000*y
profit_outdoor <- 60000*min(4,x)+80000*max(x-4,0)
total_profit <- sum(profit_indoor, profit_outdoor)

m1_needed <- x*5 + y*6
m2_needed <- x*2 + y*1
m3_needed <- x*3 + y*2
  
if((m1_needed <= 26 | m2_needed <= 12 | m3_needed <= 15 | y <= 5 | prod_vec[1]>0 | prod_vec[2]>0)){
      
return(-Inf)
  
}else{
return(production)
}

}

feasible_sol <- c(2,2)
total_profit_fun(prod_vec = feasible_sol)

infeasible_sol <- c(10,12)
total_profit_fun(prod_vec = infeasible_sol)

optim(par = feasible_sol, fn = total_profit_fun)
```

I know that return(-Inf) is meant to be used for maximization, but I think I am running into issues with my syntax and constraints. Again, my apologies if this is a newb question - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Note that with given materials you will never do more than 4X. If you build 5X then you can build 0Y and your profit is only 80000 (you can't do more than 5X). Because of this you can add constraint `X <= 4` and simplify your profit function to `70000Y + 60000X`. Because all constraints and profit function is linear you can use linear programming:

```
res <- lpSolve::lp(
  direction = "max",
  objective.in = c(60000, 70000),
  const.mat = rbind(c(5, 6), c(2, 1), c(3, 3), c(1, 0)),
  const.dir = "<=",
  const.rhs = c(26, 12, 15, 4),
  all.int = TRUE
)

res$solution
[1] 4 1
res$objval
[1] 310000
```

So you will do 4X and 1Y with profit of 310000.